# Date and time output as default into mySQL database instead

Tags: php, mysql, database, sqldatatypes

For some reason my date and time displays as a default instead of what the actual user has entered. I don't know what may be wrong. My data types in mySQL are as follows:

[image]

I tried changing the date and time to `DATE` and `TIME()` data types respectively. It doesn't let me...

[image]

I have the date and times output formated in my `$insert` query as follows:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO Booking_request_form (treatment, date, time, message, client_fk) 
VALUES('".date('Y/m/d',strtotime($_POST["Date"]))."', '".date('H:i',strtotime($_POST["Time"]))."', ...
```

Is there an east way to fix this ? Many Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using MySQL's native date/time datatypes?

Comment: @MarkBaker It doesen't let me change them. Before when I used them it didn't work for the date.

Comment: Store date and time as a single entity. Do not accept barriers to this objective

Comment: @Strawberry Would you like to say that in more understandable form? I'm new to PHP.

Comment: I would. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this:

```
date('Y/m/d',strtotime($_POST["Date"]))
```

with:

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST["Date"]))
```

Comment: Still goes in as default :/

Comment: @what is $_POST["Date"] = ?

Comment: The date from a JQuery datepicker plugin.

Comment: can you print $_POST["Date"], and get the value

Comment: If I var_dump it it returns : `1970/01/01`

Comment: That implies that the date was improper ly formatted in the first place.